# QML, How to tell the Item rendered size after scale

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

So I have an Image inside a Flickable. I want to know the size of the image after the scale is applied so that I can assign it to the Flickable's contentWidth and contentHeight. Is there a way to get the size after the scale has been applied?

```
Flickable{
    contentWidth: target.width
    contentHeight: target.height
    Image{
        id: target
        horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignLeft
        verticalAlignment: Image.AlignTop
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        scale: slider_bar.value
        source: "/image.png"
    }
}
Slider{
    id: slider_bar
    from: 0 
    to : 2
    value: 1
}
```

Another example is where I want to make the rect_1 large and the rect_2 to stay to the right of it. When running the following rect_1 resizes but rect_2 does not move.

```
Rectangle{
    id:rect_1
    height: 100
    width: 100
    scale: slider_bar.value
    transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft
    color: "green"
}

Rectangle{
    id: rect_2
    anchors.left: rect_1.right
    height: 100
    width: 100

    color:"red"
}

Slider{
    id: slider_bar
    from: 0
    to : 2
    value: 1
}
```

I could do something like

ScaledItem.qml

```
Item{
    height: implicitHeight
    width:implicitWidth
    implicitHeight: childrenRect.height * scale
    implicitWidth: childrenRect.width * scale
    scale:1
}
```

then

```
ScaledItem{
    scale: slider_bar.value
    transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft
    id:rect_1

    Rectangle{
        height: 100
        width: 100
        color: "green"
    }

}
Rectangle{
    anchors.left: rect_1.right
    height: 100
    width: 100

    color:"red"
}

Slider{
    id: slider_bar
    from: 0
    to : 2
    value: 1
}
```

Comment: `myImage.width * myImage.scale` doesn't work?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to get the rendered size of the image or item without having to do item.width * item.scale. Like is there item.renderedWidth. Image has a paintedWidth which is really what I need. So contentWidth: myImage.paintedWidth * myImage.scale when using PreserveAspectFit. Another manipulation is through using the transform: Scale{ xScale: 2; yScale: 2} So in this case I will not know the final height and width that was rendered but when using myImage.width * myImage.scale does not give me that.